# How do you check attributes for an element using xpath?

Tags: xpath

How do you check if an attribute is allowed for a specific element? For example, I want no attributes other than "action" or "method" to be in the "form" element. How can I achieve that using xpath? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would check for any for element that does not comply to your rules.

```
//form[not( count(@*) = 2 and @action and @method )]
```